# linearizing a constraint involving an absolute function

Tags: optimization, constraint, linearization, combinatorial-optimization, absolute-value

I would like to know what is the best way to linearize a constraint involving an absolute function. More precisely, imagine I have three binary variables and their relationships is as follows:

|x-y| = z.

I have so many z variables that it's value depends on x and y (all binary). That's why I am looking for an efficient way (bigM or any other way) to model efficiently this constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this is the same relationship as $x \text{ xor } y=z$. You want to enforce four logical implications:
\begin{align}
x \land y &\implies \lnot z \\
x \land \lnot y &\implies z \\
\lnot x \land y &\implies z \\
\lnot x \land \lnot y &\implies \lnot z
\end{align}
Via conjunctive normal form or otherwise, the resulting linear constraints are:
\begin{align}
(1-x)+(1-y)+(1-z) &\ge 1 \\
(1-x)+y+z &\ge 1 \\
x+(1-y)+z &\ge 1 \\
x+y+(1-z) &\ge 1
\end{align}
You can optionally relax $z$ to be nonnegative, and it will automatically take binary values.

Alternatively, you can think of the desired relationship as $x+y\mod 2=z$ and impose a single equality constraint $x+y=z+2w$, where $w$ is binary.